Power buttons and lid MIA on Windows 11 Home
I do not see the 'Power buttons and lid' options in power options advanced settings which tons of web pages refer to. Can anyone explain where they are?
Windows 11 Home (Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631)


@Giacomo1968 edited the title of my question that changed its meaning. I suggest to change it back to the original title.

The problem was solved, hopefully permanently or at least until the next Windows update, by disabling the sleep action on closing lid while on battery.
How does this affects the same setting while plugged in beats me.
Because of this, I would like to propose to change Personal Computer name to No One Knows Computer or NOKC or Not OK Computer as you may prefer.
